# Construir um programa para ler número inteiro positivo n e imprimir todos os números primos na faixa [2, n]

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

Preciso criar um algoritmo que leia um número e informe se ele é primo, e depois imprimir em uma lista todos os números primos menores ou iguais ao número lido.

Eu fiz um algoritmo que diga se é primo ou não, porém não sei como continuar...

```
n = int(input("Verificar numeros primos ate: "))
mult=0

for count in range(2,n):
    if (n % count == 0):
        print("Múltiplo de",count)
        mult += 1

if(mult==0):
    print("É primo")
else:
    print("Tem",mult," múltiplos acima de 2 e abaixo de",n)
```

Answer (score 5):

Como você já tem a principal parte do código pronta, colocarei aqui um pseudo-código de como poderia continuar, considerando que você já possui uma função chamada `é_primo` que retorna `True` ou `False`.

```
número = leia("Informe um número:")

se é_primo(número)
  escreva("Número informado é primo")
senão
  escreva("Número informado não é primo")

enquanto número > 0
  número = número - 1
  se é_primo(número)
    escreva("O número", número, "também é primo")
```

Assim você estará verificando o número informado e exibindo todos os primos menores que ele.

Answer (score 2):

Diante de uma situação prática e visando uma melhor eficiência do código seria interessante organizar a lógica da questão da seguinte forma:

1. Capturar o valor de `n`;
2. Calcular todos os **[números primos](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/o-que-e/matematica/o-que-e-numero-primo.htm)** que fossem maiores ou iguais a `"2"` e menores ou iguais a `"n"`.

Com esta lógica implementei o seguinte código:

```
def exibir_primos(n):
    li = 2
    numeros_primos = list()
    while li <= n:
        if primo(li):
            numeros_primos.append(li)
        li += 1
    return numeros_primos


def primo(m):
    i = 1
    cont = 0
    while i <= m:
        if m % i == 0:
            cont += 1
        i += 1
    if cont != 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True


num = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))

print(f'\033[32mOs números primos entre "2" e "{num}" são:\n{exibir_primos(num)}')
```

**[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/ipqhwqve-solkarped)** o funcionamento do código.

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite um número inteiro:` . Neste momento devemos digitar um número inteiro.

Posteriormente este valor é enviado para função `exibir_primos()`. A partir deste momento o bloco `while` percorrerá o intervalo fechado **[2, n]** e, com o auxílio do bloco `if`, será verificado se **cada** elemento, da respectiva interação,  é de fato um número [primo](https://www.todamateria.com.br/numeros-primos/). Então, o bloco `if` perguntará à função `primo()` se o valor `li` é de fato um número primo. Neste momento a `funcao()` calculará a quantidade de divisores de `li`. Se esta quantidade for **igual a 2**, a função `exibir_primos` receberá da função `primo()` o valor **True**. Caso contrário, a função `exibir_primos` receberá o valor **False**.

Caso o retorno da função `primo()` seja **False**, o `for` da função `exibir_primos` encerrará a respectiva interação e iniciará a próxima. Caso o retorno da função `primo()` seja **True**, o valor que foi confirmado como primo será adicionado à lista `numeros_primos`.

Esta verificação será realizada para **cada um dos números** que estiverem no intervalo fechado **[2, n]**. Depois de ter concluído estas verificações, o retorno da função - que neste caso é a lista `numeros_primos` - será exibido.

**Exemplo:**

Imagine que desejamos saber quais são os números primos maiores ou iguais a **2** e menores ou iguais a **26**.

No momento da execução do código recebemos a mensagem: `Digite um número inteiro:` . Neste momento devemos digitar...

```
26
```

...e pressionar `enter`.

A partir deste momento o código realizará todo o trabalho e nos exibirá a seguinte saída:

```
Os números primos entre "2" e "26" são:
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
```

Observe que o programa exibirá **todos os números primos maiores ou iguais a "2" e menores ou iguais a "26"**.

**Observação:**

Os número **24, 25 e 26** não foram exibidos na lista - assim como outros números - pelo fato deles não serem primos.

Comment: o que é esse `/033` no `print(f)`? O que ele faz?

Comment: @yoyo, o `\033` é um código octal que serve como carácter de escape [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria separar a tarefa em duas funções, uma que recebe um número `n` e retorna `True` caso ele seja primo e `False` no caso contrário; e outra função que também recebe o mesmo número `n`, mas retorne uma lista com todos os números primos até n. Depois, caso deseje criar uma interação com o usuário, algo como um `print('O número selecionado é primo!')`, faça isso fora das duas funções ou crie outra especialmente para esta finalidade.

No meu caso, a função `checkPrimo()` é a que vai retornar `True` ou `False` para um número específico. A função que vai gerar a lista eu chamarei de `listador()`.

```
def listador():
    
    primos = [] # Crie uma lista vazia primeiro, nesta serão implementados os números primos.

    for numero in range(2, n): # posso começar o range() com 2, porque 0 e 1 já se sabe que não são primos.

        if checkPrimo(numero) == True: # Caso a condição seja verdadeira, ou seja, o número seja primo, o bloco será executado. O fragmento "== True" é facultativo.
            primos.append(numero) # Isto adicionará 'numero' à lista 'primos'.

    return primos # Por fim, retorna-se a lista para que esta função possa ser encadeada dentro de outras funções com mais praticidade.
```

Vale lembrar que `range(2, n)` nunca acrescentará `n` dentro da lista, isto porque a última iteração de `range()` sempre é "`n-1`". Caso deseje acrescentá-lo à lista, simplesmente mude para `range(2, n + 1)`.

A última linha, a que retorna a lista `primos`, é opcional; fica a seu critério escrevê-la ou não. Mesmo que não seja retornada, ela continuará disponível fora da função após esta ter sido executada.